# How to get difference between two dates in javascript when they are of different months

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to get the difference between two dates when they are in different months or years. I have used the code below

var d1= lastexecdate.split(".");

var d2= jabusinessdate.split(".");

var date1= new Date(d1[2], d1[1],d1[0]);

var date2= new Date(d2[2], d2[1],d2[0]);

var timeDiff= (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

var diffdays= Math.ceil(timeDiff/(1000*3600*24));

When i use dates such as 17.10.2014 and 19.10.2014 it gives me a differenc of two which is perfect. But when i use dates such as 31.10.2014 and 1.11.2014 it gives me a result as zero where as the actual result should have been 1. That is when the months or year are different it shows anomaly in result. Please suggest me some ideas or some functions which i can use to get appropriate result.

Comment: My application does not support moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript months are indexed from 0. So January has index 0 and December has index 11. In your case when you are specifying the date 31.10.2014, you have to actually pass 9 as the month parameter to the date constructor. Similarly 10 instead of 11 to the date constructor.

Example:

For "31.10.2014":

```
var date1 = new Date(2014,9,31);
```

For "1.11.2014":

```
var date2 = new Date(2014,10,1);
```

Now you do the calculation as follows:

```
var timeDiff =Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

this will give result 1.

so all you have to do is subtract 1 from the month in your code as follows:

```
var date1= new Date(d1[2], d1[1] - 1,d1[0]);

var date2= new Date(d2[2], d2[1] - 1,d2[0]);
```

Comment: Will it give a difference of 1 if the dates are 31.12.2014 and 1.1.2015? As my batches are running i cannot check if it will work for change in year or not.

Comment: Yes it will give the correct difference as long as you maintain the zero indexing rule for months. You have to provide 0 for January and 11 for December.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will do that. I tested with different years as well as different months. Since the time information is irrelevant for you, take it out of the way by giving it the same value for both dates, such as 00:00:00 as you stated in your comment

```
function dateDiff(date1, date2){
    var diff = {}                           // return initialisation
    var tmp = date2 - date1;

    tmp = Math.floor(tmp/1000);             // Number of seconds between the     two dates
    diff.sec = tmp % 60;                    // Extracting the number of    seconds

    tmp = Math.floor((tmp-diff.sec)/60);    // Number of minutes (integer    part)
    diff.min = tmp % 60;                    // Extracting the number of     minutes

    tmp = Math.floor((tmp-diff.min)/60);    // Number of hours (integer     part)
    diff.hour = tmp % 24;                   // Extracting the number of     hours

    tmp = Math.floor((tmp-diff.hour)/24);   // Number of remaining days
    diff.day = tmp;

    return diff;
}

    date1 = new Date('2013-08-25 00:00:00');
    date2 = new Date('2013-10-29 22:16:57');
    diff = dateDiff(date1, date2);
    alert("Between "+date1.toString()+" and "+date2.toString()+" there are         "+diff.day+" days, "+diff.hour+" hours, "+diff.min+" minutes and "+diff.sec+"       seconds");
```

Here is two image captures of obtained result. First with different years and second with different months.

[image: years different]

[image: months different]